# Image saved but will not display after saving file in node

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js

I am uploading images and saving them to the server. They have the exact same name except the very last character which is 1 or 2 etc. When I try to display the image using the exact same code as the other images I get an error saying

> GET http://www.suburbsdirectory.co.za/images/profiles/5Business1Pic.jpg 404 (Not Found)

```js
if (profile_image.substring(0, 8) == 'uploads/') {
  fs.copyFile(`public/${profile_image}`, `public/images/profiles/${id}ProfilePic.jpg`, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err)
    };
  })
  setTimeout(() => {
    fs.unlink(`public/${business_image1}`, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err)
      };
    })
  }, 200)
}

if (business_image1.substring(0, 8) == 'uploads/') {
  fs.copyFile(`public/${business_image1}`, `public/images/profiles/${id}Business1Pic.jpg`, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err)
    };
  })
  setTimeout(() => {
    fs.unlink(`public/${business_image1}`, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err)
      };
    })
  }, 250)
}

if (business_image2.substring(0, 8) == 'uploads/') {
  fs.copyFile(`public/${business_image2}`, `public/images/profiles/${id}Business2Pic.jpg`, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err)
    };
  })
  setTimeout(() => {
    fs.unlink(`public/${business_image2}`, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err)
      };
    })
  }, 300)
}

if (business_image3.substring(0, 8) == 'uploads/') {
  fs.copyFile(`public/${business_image3}`, `public/images/profiles/${id}Business3Pic.jpg`, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err)
    };
  })
  setTimeout(() => {
    fs.unlink(`public/${business_image3}`, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err)
      };
    })
  }, 350)
}
```

When I save the link to the database field I am excluding "public". Here is code calling the image in jquery:

```
$('#business_image1').attr('src', result[0].business_image1).css('width', `${profileImageWidth}`)
$('#business_image2').attr('src', result[0].business_image2).css('width', `${profileImageWidth}`)
$('#business_image3').attr('src', result[0].business_image3).css('width', `${profileImageWidth}`)
```

`business_image2` & `3` display perfectly but not number `1`. Here is the data retrieved from sql query (as mentioned earlier the file is saved.)

```
business_image1: "/images/profiles/5Business1Pic.jpg"
business_image2: "/images/profiles/5Business2Pic.jpg"
business_image3: "/images/profiles/5Business3Pic.jpg"
```

Here are the files that have been saved:

[image: Files succesfully uploaded]

I have been trying for hours but cannot fathom where I am making a mistake.

Comment: What exactly returns that 404 code? Is it shown in the console where you adding it with `$('#business_image1').attr('src', result[0].business_image1).css('width', \`${profileImageWidth}\`)`, right?

Comment: @extempl - exactly that yes.

Comment: Is the image accessible for you on the web? Will it work if you just add image in html?

Comment: Can you create a simple html on your site with these three images and share it so we can see the actual issue?